# hmm variable number states

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have looked around for a while but cant seem to find any literature on this but can't seem to find a treatment. I have a set A of observations at time $t_n$ $A = \{A_1... A_n\}$ Further I know that these observations have a bayesian probability (that I will treat as emission probabilities) given unknown hidden states defined at each of these times $S = \{S_1...S_n \}$

The trouble (potentially) is that there are a different number of potential hidden states at each time period, and consequently there are $n$ different transition matrices. I think viterbi breaks down here, as there might be a strong solution up to $t_{n-1}$ that becomes non optimal as there is only a transition permitted to a highly prohibited final hidden state. Is there a nice way to solve this problem other than an exhaustive search?

Comment: or any ways to generate approximate solutions faster than exhaustive search?

Comment: For a given time period, do you know the number of potential hidden states? How widely does the number range over time?

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example, with no restrictions at all on the number of states at each time or the relationship between states at different times,  you have a saturated model where estimation is meaningless. With most reasonable more specific problem formulations that come to mind I could see some sort of dynamic programming approach being simple enough. Perhaps a forward summation and backwards sampling approach, depending again on the detailed specification?

Comment: The number of hidden states will vary between 5-10

Comment: I actually have solved it. I think viterbi will work fine in this case